# How can I convert an int to a string (char*) in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, integer, character

I have been looking all over the web for that and I cannot find anything. I currently have an integer (`int`) and I need to convert it to `char*` (NOT `char[]`). I cannot get it to work in any way so far. thanks

edit:
I tried doing the following with no luck

```
int i = 8;
char *charArray = i + '0';
```

edit 2: 
as I am new to C I thing I have misunderstood something here.
I am currently using the Pebble SDK (smart watch) and I am trying to convert from an int to string to pass it in the function [text_layer_set_text()](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/group___text_layer.html#ga19406f772604d595c5c1af7222992449) 
When I am using the format: `char *example = "4"` my code works great. Although, no matter which way I try to pass my ints in the layer doesn't behave as expected

Comment: Could you please post an example (how are you trying to do even if it's wrong)?

Comment: Please show your last attempt that failed.

Comment: @Gopi `char *example` is certainly not a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear.

If you want a `char *` as a generic pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    char *p = (char *)&x;

    printf("%d\n", *(int *)p);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want `char *` as a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    char *p = malloc(32);

    sprintf(p, "%d", x);
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:

> I am using the pebble (smartwatch sdk) and the sprintf() function is
>   not supported

Use the modulo division to get each digit and then reverse the string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *p = malloc(32);
    int i = 0, x = 5374;
    int temp, len;

    temp = abs(x); /* support for negatives */
    if (x < 0) p[i++] = '-'; /* support for negatives */
    do {
        p[i++] = '0' + temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;
    } while (temp);
    p[i] = '\0';
    if (x < 0) p++; /* support for negatives */
    len = strlen(p) - 1;
    for(i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
        temp = p[len];
        p[len] = p[i];
        p[i] = temp;
        len--;
    }
    if (x < 0) p--; /* support for negatives */
    printf("%s\n", p);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using the pebble (smartwatch sdk) and the sprintf() function is not supported.

Comment: Although I dont fully understand the code your example gives a possible solution to my problem. Thank you

Comment: can you please give me an example for a single-digit positive int so I can easier understand the code is it like that?: `char *p = malloc(32);
    int x = 5;

    p[i++] = '0' + x;
    p[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @Rakim, Yes!! its like that

Comment: The fact that I need to allocate memory on the heap (malloc) bugs me. Why can I not just create my variable in the stack? thanks

Comment: Of course you can, use `char s[32], *p = s;` instead of `char *p = malloc(32);`, where is the problem?

Comment: I did try  the following: `char p[2];

    p[0] = '0' + 3;
    p[1] = '\0';` trying to just display number 3. your code was  working perfectly. Using that I get no warning but I get nothing on my screen.

Comment: How do you print the result?

Comment: I am using the function stated in my question from the pebble SDK. [text_layer_set_text()](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/c/group___text_layer.html#ga19406f772604d595c5c1af7222992449)

Comment: I don't know about this API, but there is a note in the provided link: `The string is not copied, so its buffer most likely cannot be stack allocated`

Comment: I did set it as a static global var! works! thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

1. declare and define a `char *` array, allocate memory.
2. use `sprintf()`. Check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

Write the code yourself and let us know the output.

---

EDIT:

you can always cast the address of the `int` variable to a `char *`, but be very careful while using the `char *`.

```
int i = 10;
char * p = NULL;
p = (char *)&i;
```

if you want to `*p` to   *behave as* integer, don't forget to cast `p` back to `int *` before use. Otherwise, you'll be amazed.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using the pebble (smartwatch sdk) and the function is not supported.

Comment: I dont get any errors or anything but nothing is displayed in my textlayer. I'm sure there is nothing wrong with the rest of the code because passing in `char *example = "8"` as a parameter to the function works great

Comment: @Rakim I think, I (and everybody else, for that matter) misunderstood your problem. `char *example = "8"` is a whole different story. Please state your problem in detail.

Comment: can you further explain as I am new in C and I dont get the difference? Thanks

Comment: @Rakim sure will. But, before that, you need to tell us what _exactly_ do you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code:

```
int a = 1234;
char *str = malloc(20);
sprintf(str, "%d", a);
printf("%s\n",str);
```

Comment: I stated in the question than I want a char* and not a char[] but thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt would work -- if you were going for a `char` instead of a `char*`.

```
int i = 8;
char c  = (char) (i + '0');    // c = "8"
```

The method is technically not guaranteed to work -- since the Standard won't assume that you are using ASCII, UNICODE, or EBCDIC -- but using some character system besides those three is virtually unheard of, so you're safe.  It will also only work for integers in the range [0-9].

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

....
char buffer[32] = {'\0'};

int  a = 23;

itoa(a,buffer,10);   // here 10 means decimal
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you give as working, char *example = "8"//
This should be char *example = '8'; You are creating pointer to a char not a string, an array of chars.

You want an array of chars representing int as an ascii? (or unicode?)

```
char buffer[32] = {'\0'}; //or char *buffer = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));  
int a = 10;
itoa(a, buffer,10);//convert an integer that can be represented by up to 32 chars
```

Had a look (for 30 seconds) at pebble api and found the APIs  sprintf version,Worth a look? 
    `int snprintf(char * str, size_t n, const * fmt, ... )`

Comment: if using *buffer in iota may require &buffer, try it